# ValueError at /new_topic/ Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django......>": "Topic.owner" must be a "User" instance

Tags: django, django-views

*Any time i insert data the above error occurred! *

```
# my views 
def new_topic(request):
"""Add a new topic."""

if request.method != 'POST':
    # No data submitted; create a blank form.
    form = TopicForm()
else:
    # POST data submitted; process data.
    form = TopicForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():

        new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
        new_topic.owner = request.user #this where i think, i'm messing up!
        new_topic.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)
```

*model representing each Topic *
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.id, filename)

class Topic(models.Model):
       """A topic the user is learning about"""
       text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
       date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
       image = models.ImageField()
       height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
       width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)

       owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

       def __str__(self):
            """Return a string representation of the model."""
            return self.text
```

Any help please!

Comment: Can you `print(request.user)` in your view ? What it represents ? It will show in your runserver command log. I'm assuming that your view isn't indented like this in your real code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `new_topic.owner = request.user` should be fine if the user is logged in. However if the user is not logged in, then trying to assign an anonymous user would cause problems.

You can prevent this by using the [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator, so that only logged-in users can access the view.

```
@login_required
def new_topic(request):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot "Alasdair"   for clarifying,  now its works!   
and i've also imported and used the provided  decorator 
to prevent unlogged users from creating new_topics! 
thanks again!